# How to display the value which is inside computed in VueJS2?

Tags: vuejs2

How to display the value which is inside computed  in VueJS2 ? Actually i'm trying to return the value click*2 using computed property. So i'm displaying the output using the expression `{{counter}}`. But i'm not getting any output, at first it was set to counter to 0 (stored in the data). Even i didn't use v-once. So why my counter value is not updating through computed property?

```
 <div id="app4">
    <p>counter : {{ counter }}</p>
    <p>clicks : {{ click }}</p>
    <button v-on:click="increment">increment</button>
  </div>

    <script>
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app4',
        data: {
           counter:0,
           click: 0,
        },
       methods: {
           increment() {

               this.click++;
           }
       },
       computed: {
           counter() {
               return this.click * 2;
           }
       }
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `counter` from data and it will work. You have two properties that shadow one another - one in `data` and the other in `computed`.

Comment: I have one doubt regarding that. First i'm loading the value of counter from the `data` . I did't use `v-once` directive for that counter. So why the counter value is not updating through `computed` ?

Comment: Because computed properties are ignored during rendering if there is a data property with the same name. You should be getting Vue warnings about that when you load the app. Also, I can't understand why you would want to have `counter` both as data and computed property.

Comment: noted the point. Actually i didn't get any Vue warning in my browser. Thanks man :)